# targeting frame names

Tags: html

Google page does not show in iframe when I click on the link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.ca" target="frame" >google</a>
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="500" height="500" />
```

Comment: You just did. I see it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question... If you want the frame to respond to the amazon link and not the google one, then don't set your `target="frame"` on the google link.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `target="frame"` from google link

```
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://amazon.com" target="frame" >amazon</a>
```